# External configuration for MSAL other than Decorator

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

I'm very new to Angular and recently required to work on MSAL. So here is how I am configuring the MSAL.

Under App Module **Imports**

```
MsalModule.forRoot({
  auth: {
    clientId: 'myclientid', // This is your client ID
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid', // This is your tenant ID
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200'// This is your redirect URI
    //redirectUri: 'https://myapiurl.com'// This is your redirect URI
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
    storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // Set to true for Internet Explorer 11
  },
}, {
  popUp: !isIE,
  consentScopes: [
              'user.read',
              'openid',
              'apiguid/user_impersonation',
            ], 
  unprotectedResources: [],
  protectedResourceMap: [
              [
                'https://localhost:44331/',
                ['apiguid/user_impersonation'],
              ],
              [
                'https://myapiurl.com/userimpersonation/',
                ['apiguid/user_impersonation'],
              ],
            ], 
  extraQueryParameters: {}
})
```

But my problem is since the configurations are in decorator, I found its difficult to use Dynamic values for each of those properties like ClientID.

So is there is any way in MSAL to load the configuration as a JSON file or from a different function

Answer (score 0):

I have got a solution which I think is a very nice one and with that I got it working.

Sharing to those who having the same issue

[How to initialize msal configurations using APP_INITIALIZER](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1403)